# Request referer gets cached

Tags: 8, caching

I need to grab referer and save it for the first time (I save it to sessions) and when the user gets to a specific page forward it. My problem is that after opening page with the **same** referer few times, I am not getting referer anymore. I tried it with few different browsers in private/incognito mode but after a few tries it gets cached and does not return anymore. My Code :

```
function HOOK_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables)
{
    $request = Drupal::request();

    var_dump($request->headers->get('referer')); //stops dumping after few times

    $_SESSION['referer']['url'] = $request->headers->get('referer');
    $variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'headers:referer';
}
```

Is there a way to save referer for every anonymous user that comes to website?

Comment: For anonymous traffic you need to disable the page cache. Add this line to your code `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` or if this is for all pages you can uninstall the module *Internal Page Cache*. I agree with the answer from @Kevin that the code placement could be improved, because the hook you are using is executed multiple times per request (one time for every template), as long as the template is not cached, which will happen eventually for all templates. So better choose one and disable the caching of that specific template.

Comment: @4k4 well I need it for any page anonymous user lands on first, so I need to uninstall internal page cache, but will that affect speed of website?

Comment: Of course, when you process each anonymous request individually this will slow down your site. But this problem is not Drupal specific. This is why most times such tasks are realized client side in javascript.

Comment: @4k4 so maybe it would be better if I create client javascript code that would send referer over ajax to a custom module and then in the module I just save it to the session, then I won't have to disable internal cache. thank you very much

Comment: I think you can do it all client side until the user clicks on the link for leaving the site, then you can add the referer as query parameter, for which the page cache varies by default.

Comment: I transferred it to client javascript and saved with SessionStorage, and when on form page just use it with javascript, it is working without a problem, thank you @4k4 again.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, i won't use a hook but the drupal eventSubscriber :

First your need to make a custom module with the file for declare to drupal your new service :

> myModule.services.yml

```
services:
  myModule.services:
    class: Drupal\myModule\EventSubscriber\MyServiceSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Then in the file :

> myModule/src/EventSubscriber/MyServiceSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\myModule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

    /**
     * Class myServiceSubscriber.
     *
     * @package Drupal\myModule
     */
    class MyServiceSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

        public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
           // here your code, this method ll be call on every call request
           // so you can code your logic here
        }


      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
      static function getSubscribedEvents() {

          $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest', 900];

          return $events;
      }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this also but my priority was 30, and I see you used 900, can maybe that make a difference?

Comment: No its because higher priority numbers get executed first and i paste this code from my module where i have more than one event

Comment: You need to clear the cache after enable the module

Comment: as @4k4 mentioned in comments above I would still need to `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` or uninstall internal cache module completely what would slow down the website, I transferred logic to client javascript code, thank you for suggestion @Kevin

Comment: The page cache is a middleware, request event subscribers are *not* called on a page cache hit. You can register your own middleware and act before/after the page cache on every request (except when when you also use an external cache like Varnish) but yes, it's quite possible that whatever needs to be done in such a case is better done in JS.